# How to remove an event listener from a div that has an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

If a div has an event, and the function is an anonymous function passed in some long minified JS. How can I from console remove that event?

I have tried cloning and replacing, or replacing outerHTML, but both methods affect all the innerHTML.

Is there a way to remove the eventListener without referencing the function itself? Just remove all the eventlisteners attached to the div?

Comment: `but both methods affect all the innerHTML.` Do you mean that the problem with this is that any listeners attached to *children* get removed too, which you don't want? (you only want the listener attached to the outer div to be removed?) Or, what is the issue with changing the `innerHTML`?

Comment: One answer is easy: No to this: _Is there a way to remove the eventListener without referencing the function itself?_ the reason is due to how JS compares Objects (function objects in this case). They are compared by reference - so both `add..` and `remove...` must use a _reference_ to the same object.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, do not affect any inner events or elements, or their state.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What I don't understand is you can easily remove attributes like style, classes etc... without having to reference anything other than getElementById.thing = null

Comment: right - that's because the run time is looking up the function used as an event handler in what amounts to a lookup table. It evaluates which event to remove based upon a comparison of the provided reference (to the function) and all the ones stored in the lookup table. It is the comparison that differentiates this particular thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to *replace* the `div` that has the listener you want to remove with an identical div (but without the listener) - iterate through the original `div`'s `childNodes` and append them to the new `div`. As you can see in the example below, the `#outer` container gets replaced, but the listener on `#inner` is still preserved:

```js
const [outer, inner] = ['outer', 'inner'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));
outer.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('outer clicked'));
inner.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('inner clicked'));

const outerParent = outer.parentElement;
const newOuter = outer.cloneNode(false);
/*
 * make sure to use false above for a shallow copy (no children);
 * if you create and use a deep copy, listeners attached to outer's old children won't be preserved
 * (the listeners don't get copied)
 */
 
[...outer.childNodes].forEach(child => {
  newOuter.append(child)
});
outerParent.replaceChild(newOuter, outer);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  inside outer
  <div id="inner">
    inner
  </div>
  inside outer
</div>
```